# Using named address within VBA formula

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following named address:

```
PLVlast = Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address
```

I want to divide a cell (N2) by that address. AB2 will have the result.

```
Range("AB2") = "=(RC[-14]/PLVlast)"
```

The error: Excel formula in AB2 shows the following

```
=(N2/PLVlast)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the result need to be dynamic (if new data is added in ColD for example) ?

Comment: @TimWilliams I can see one of your formulas is about to be posted!! :D

Comment: @TimWilliams yes because it will be copied down "x" amount of rows depending on source data

Comment: @carter Tim is asking whether the formula in the existing cells need to automatically update if new data is added to column D.  So when you first set the formula in AB2 it might be `=N2/$D$25` but then, if you add something in $D$26, do you want the formula to automatically be equivalent to `=N2/$D$26`.  (Tim is good at creating formulas that will pick up the last value in a column, without VBA involvement.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the value of the `PLVlast` variable, not the variable name.  And you also need to set `PLVlast` to have an R1C1 address format if you intend to use its value in an R1C1 formula:

```
PLVlast = Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

Range("AB2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-14]/" & PLVlast & ")"
```

---

Or, if you want to use A1 notation throughout:

```
PLVlast = Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address

Range("AB2").Formula = "=(N2/" & PLVlast & ")"
```

---

Or, if you want to apply this formula to all cells in column AB, down to the row before the last one in column D (I'm assuming that is some sort of total row):

```
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("D" & Sheets("Summary").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("AB2").Resize(lastRow - 2, 1).Formula = "=(N2/D$" & lastRow & ")"
```

Comment: I had tried that and kept getting error 1004. Just tried again to confirm.

Comment: @carter Answer fixed - had forgotten that you were setting `PLVlast` to an A1 notation address

Comment: Perfect - Thank you! Would it be easier to not use R1C1?

Comment: @carter - Answer edited to show A1 notation method, and also how to apply the formula to multiple rows

Comment: @carter - BTW, is your AB2 cell on the "Summary" sheet too?  If it is, you should really use `Sheets("Summary").Range("AB2")`.  If it isn't, you will need to change the formula to refer to the sheet - e.g. `... /Summary!" & PLVlast ...`.

Comment: it wasn't, and I did need to change the formula to  `Range("AB2").FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-3]/" & "Summary!" & MLVlast & ")"`. Your solution got me there though - thanks again